# Renderscript with Android NDK and CMake

Tags: cmake, android-ndk, renderscript, android-renderscript

I am trying to build a custom kernel with Renderscript in Android native development. But got stuck at the compilation step. I took reference with the https://github.com/rpattabi/renderscript-ndk-cmake. Below is my CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

if(${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} MATCHES Release)
 set (SRC_RS_GENERATED_PATH 
    build/generated/source/rs/release)
 else()
    set (SRC_RS_GENERATED_PATH 
    build/generated/source/rs/debug)
endif()
    set(RENDER_SCRIPT_HEADERS_PATH ${CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK}/toolchains/renderscript/prebuilt/${ANDROID_HOST_TAG}/platform/rs)

include_directories(
        ${RENDER_SCRIPT_HEADERS_PATH}/cpp
        ${RENDER_SCRIPT_HEADERS_PATH}/scriptc
        ${RENDER_SCRIPT_HEADERS_PATH}
        ${SRC_RS_GENERATED_PATH}
)

set(RENDER_SCRIPT_LIB_PATH ${CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK}/toolchains/renderscript/prebuilt/${ANDROID_HOST_TAG}/platform/${ANDROID_SYSROOT_ABI})
find_library(rscript
        NAMES RScpp_static libRScpp_static.a
        HINTS ${RENDER_SCRIPT_LIB_PATH}/
        )
find_library(blasv8
        NAMES blasV8 libblasV8.so
        HINTS ${RENDER_SCRIPT_LIB_PATH}/)
find_library(rssupport
        NAMES libRSSupport.so
        HINTS ${RENDER_SCRIPT_LIB_PATH}/)

add_library(
        renderscript
        SHARED
        RenderScript.cpp
        threshold.rs
    ${SRC_RS_GENERATED_PATH}/ScriptC_threshold.cpp #This file is missing <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
)

target_link_libraries(
        renderscript
        log
        ${rscript}
        ${rssupport}
        ${blasv8}
        android
        jnigraphics
        )
```

The first few parts are just finding the headers for prebuilt library for renderscript in the Android NDK.

The error comes at building the `renderscript` library part. It suppose to build the `threshold.rs` file, and generate a header and cpp pair (ScriptC_threshold.h and ScriptC_threshold.cpp), which the source code for `renderscript` will include.

However, the build script does not generate the `ScriptC_threshold.h` headers. What is the procedure or CMakeList configuration that allows me to generate the header file from `rs` files?

**Update 1**
As suggested by Dan, I change the build script from cmakeList to Android.mk. However, I got another error

```
[x86] Compile RS     : renderscript <= threshold.rs

  error: error opening 'E:/dev/android/RenderScriptMk/app/E:/dev/android/RenderScriptMk/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/x86/objs-debug/renderscript/\threshold.bc': Invalid argument
  make: *** [E:/dev/android/RenderScriptMk/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/x86/objs-debug/renderscript/threshold.o] Error 1
```

It appears the build process failed to generate the .bc file from the .rs script. I am stuck again. I uploaded my code to [Github](https://github.com/cjf12harry/RenderScriptMk), it should be able to reproduce.

Comment: Why not just use ndk-build where renderscript is actually supported?

Comment: @Dan Albert
Currently I am using Android Studio 3.5.1 and NDK r20. By default C++ support project uses CMake, so I went down this route. Also I believe CMake can do what ndk-build does. Actually I successfully linked to the prebuilt render script library, and used its blur kernel. It is when I want to write my custom kernel (threshold.rs) that got stuck

Comment: You're better off with ndk-build for renderscript. ndk-build actually supports it; you don't have to build all the support yourself.

Comment: I converted my project to using ndk-build and Android.mk based. but now I got another error ```'E:/dev/android/RenderScriptMk/app/E:/dev/android/RenderScriptMk/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/x86/objs-debug/renderscript/\threshold.bc': Invalid argument
  make: *** [E:/dev/android/RenderScriptMk/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/x86/objs-debug/renderscript/threshold.o]```

Comment: Seems that's a bug on Windows when `NDK_OUT` is set: https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/856.